# enabling auto completion for apt-get install in docker (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, apt, docker, auto-completion

I am running an ubuntu container in docker.
I tried everything I found online, including:

[auto-completion does not work for "sudo apt-get install"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209778/auto-completion-does-not-work-for-sudo-apt-get-install)

but pressing "tab" still has no effect

Answer (score 20):

I know this is old, but I ran into it too.  It's clear what is failing with the help of debug mode in bash: `set -x`.

Once you get your into your docker container and `apt install bash-completion`, and edit your users `.bashrc` to source the right directory, and logout/login (basically follow the steps in the [q/a you referenced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209778/auto-completion-does-not-work-for-sudo-apt-get-install).

The command that is failing is:

```
# apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames firefox
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

The '--no-generate' in there should give you a clue what is going on (something, something, cache is missing).  If you run without it, you get back a list of packages.

This led me to search in some of my reference links with how this system is supposed to work, and eventually inspect the apt configuration:

```
root@edb76551d1dd:/var/cache/apt# apt-config dump |grep Dir::C
Dir::Cache "var/cache/apt/";
Dir::Cache::archives "archives/";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "";
```

Notice that 'pkgcache' is empty.  Try that on a normal install (like a lxd container), and you will notice it is set.  This led me to the place that configuration information is stored, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`.  On the docker container:

```
# grep cache *
[...]
docker-clean:Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
```

You'll notice above that docker images are actively unsetting this value, to keep apt from storing the cache file locally (to reduce image size).  I commented out everything in that file, so the file now looks like:

```
# file: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean 
#DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
#APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
#Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
```

And now, things work (after running `apt update` once:

```
# apt update
[...]        
# apt install firefox-d<tab>   
firefox-dbg  firefox-dev
```

## References

These helped me figure out how this system worked...

- [auto-completion does not work for "sudo apt-get install"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209778)
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReducingDiskFootprint
- https://github.com/debops/ansible-php/issues/22